# Rails - Validating a record without adding errors

Tags: ruby-on-rails

Question is as above. I have a record that I need to validate before deciding which form to show. The record is created invalid, and we check its validity to see if the form the user is on is the initial registration form or a subsequent form.

My issue is when I call `record.valid?` the record gets various error messages added to it which are then incorrectly displayed on the registration form. It's not possible for me to simply clear the errors after validating as I need the errors present if the user enters invalid data.

Is there any way to call `valid?` or an equivalent that does not add errors to the instance?

Thanks in advance

Comment: My initial thought was why not just `if record.valid? #do_something else record.errors.clear #do_something_different` but your contradictory statements have me a bit confused. You want to validate and keep the errors *"It's not possible for me to simply clear the errors after validating as I need the errors present if the user enters invalid data."* but then you don't want them generated in the first place *"Is there any way to call valid? or an equivalent that does not add errors to the instance?"*.

Comment: Sorry for not explaining clearly. At the initial registration form, the record will have errors on their profile which I do not want to display as it is the first time they visit the form. If however the user is on the edit profile page (which I can tell by calling .valid?) then I need any errors that are present to persist as they will be user generated.

Comment: How does `valid?` tell you if they are editting? Why no use something like `profile.persisted?`? Please add some code to this question as it seems you may be going about this is a less than idiomatic fashion and other can offer suggestions based on fact rather than conjecture

Comment: Because their profile gets created invalid. If their profile is invalid they have not cleared the registration form, and if it is valid they must have cleared it.

Comment: I appreciate a lot of the details are in code I've not posted however I've been able to use a below answer, thanks for your time

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You want to validates with a steps system ? I think you can look at with_options block.

**example :**

```
  with_options condition do
   # your validations or anything...
   # validates :attribute
  end
```

**documentation :**
https://apidock.com/rails/Object/with_options

With good conditions you will avoid adding errors on validations already "validated" and focus on the new ones.

I hope I understood your request correctly.

Answer (score 1):

After calling `valid?` you can clear errors from object ie.
`record.errors.clear`

Comment: I need to keep errors that are already present and can't simply clear them

Comment: check this https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40578350/multi-step-activerecords-model-validation